# Python can't execute query on Access DB with MySQL linked table

Tags: python, mysql, ms-access, ms-office, pyodbc

I'm struggling with an issue using pyodbc: I've created an Access database with some linked tables on MySQL (we're migrating the company DB's), this DB is accessed by MS Access ODBC Driver through pyodbc, and in the python code we execute some queries on that DB. It works normally when INSERTING data in a linked table, but when we have to UPDATE an access table using data from a linked mysql table, pyodbc delivers this message:

```
('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] The Microsoft access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time. (-1611) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

- The same UPDATE query works normally when executed directly in Access, this issue only happens when pyodbc tries to execute it.
- I've found a topic on StackOverFlow about it, someone said that the problem is with Office 365. We have a test system working fine on Office 2019, with the same queries and the same DB, problem is: we can't migrate the system to Access 2019 on production.

Comment: What do you mean by "working fine on Office 2019" - isn't that by using Access 2019?